# Condensation point in Lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology

So I have a [Lindelöf space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space). How do I show that every uncountable subset of the Lindelöf space $X$ has a condensation point.

I started with letting $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X$, and $U_m$ be a countable subcover (possible since x is Lindelöf). So, I can choose an $x\in U_m \subset \mathscr{U}$, right?

If I let $A\subset X$ be an uncountable set in $X$. Should I consider the intersection of $A$ and $U_m$ next then? Or is there anything wrong in the way I chose $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Try to prove by contrapositive. Suppose that some $A$ doesn't have a condensation point; then for every point $x\in X$, there is some open neighborhood that contains at most countably many elements of $A$. Use these neighborhoods to construct $\mathscr{U}$ and $U_m$, can you see how this shows that $A$ is countable?

Comment: Actually, there's no need for a contradiction. This general approach lets you show that if $A\subseteq X$ has no condensation point, then $A$ is countable.

Comment: @Eric Stucky: How do you know that every open neighborhood contains at most countably many elements of $A$? And do we get the contradiction from intersecting $A$ and $U_m$?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Sorry, my hint was badly mangled; I've changed it to be more accurate (and also to incorporate Cameron's suggestion). You only get one such neighborhood per point.

Comment: @Eric Stucky: can I construct the open cover $\mathscr{U}$ from a collection of open sets $U$ in $X$, and then pick out $U_m$, which is a countable subcover. Then how do I conclude that A is countable from that?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Think about the definition of sets $U\in\mathscr{U}$.